# Save a long string in SQL database using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to save the contents of a website to my database using Entity Framework. However, when the length of the HTML > 4000, I get these validation errors:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.DLL WebDev.WebServer40.exe Information: 0 :
>   Property: RawData Error: The field RawData must be a string or array
>   type with a maximum length of '4000'.

Any idea how to get around this? RawData is being created as NVARCHAR(4000) but a better type would be TEXT. Can I force that somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data type is the RawData property? Is it not a string?

Comment: RawData is simply a string in C#. I'm using SQL CE (simply judging by my connection string).

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect, it appears that SQL CE does not support `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, sorry.

Comment: @AdamWenger - I don't have to use SQL CE. Actually I don't even fully understand how EF works with the different SQL database types.

Comment: Simon, when we use EF to generate a database schema for SQL Server 2008, strings are generated as NVARCHAR(MAX), so if you were using standard edition, I think it should work for you as desired.

Comment: @AdamWenger - changing to SQL Server 2008 worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TEXT` data type has been deprecated in favor of `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, I would use that to save yourself refactoring down the road.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662.aspx

SQL CE doesn't support `NVARCHAR(MAX)` so it limits your strings to `NVARCHAR(4000)`

If it is possible to use SQL Server 2008, Entity Framework will generate `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns for you from your strings.

Comment: Then how do I boost the value of MAX?

Comment: To clarify this answer -- move to SQL Server 2008. Don't use CE.

Comment: Are you sure about the limit of 4000 in SQLCE (4) ? I think it works if you use the [MaxLegth]  annotation.... I 'm using it myself and it works...

Comment: I am not positive, no.  I saw a reference in MSDN which showed the 4000 limit for `nvarchar` for CE 4.0, as well as in information from the OP and updated my answer to try to explain how they were able to address their issue of not being able to store long strings.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28SQL.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I'm using SQL CE 4.0 and having the very same problem. I managed to solve it using the following DataAnnotation (i like annotations  :) )

```
public class Page
    {
        [Key]
        public int PageId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i can save whatever content in the Content property!

Answer (score 1):

TEXT type would be a better option. However this is memory hungry compared to a limited nvarchar.

Alternatively you can use BLOB but will require you to do some string data processing.

Comment: There won't be a ton of rows in this table so should I just go with TEXT? Is BLOB more memory efficient?

Comment: TEXT is easier to handle as you are putting the values as strings. If you use BLOB, you have to convert that into binary when saving and then reconvert that to string when you read it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EF Code First?  You can designate the text type in an entity mapping file.

Example mapping file:

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnType("text");
}
```

Then you have to register your mapping file in your dbContext class in the OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Where does the mapping file go? I'm trying to figure out what 'this.Property' refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I [almost] used Kyle Nunery's answer except that as I needed it for MySql and large strings to be stored, I thought it would be useful to know what else you can use instead of the `"text"` type.

The maximum amount of data that can be stored in each data type is as follows:

TINYTEXT     256 bytes

TEXT         65,535 bytes   ~64kb

MEDIUMTEXT   16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB

LONGTEXT     4,294,967,295 bytes    ~4GB